# displaying JSON data in Tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

below is the JSON i want to parse it in such a way that for e.g date 1st should all events in that section of table and 2nd date should show all related events in another section 
I am parsing using below code but i am not getting required sequence

```
   SBJsonParser *parser= [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
appDelegate.books1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
appDelegate.dates =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for (int j=0;j<10; j++) {

    NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:j];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"date"]);

    Date  *aDate = [[Date alloc] initWithDictionary:[results objectAtIndex:j]];
    [appDelegate.dates addObject:aDate];



    [aDate release];




}


for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

    NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:i];

    NSArray *activitiesArray = [dictOne objectForKey:@"events"];
    NSDictionary *dictTwo = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *eventDict=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"event"];
//  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"date"]);
//  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]);
//  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [eventDict objectForKey:@"location"]);


    NSInteger*date=[dictOne objectForKey:@"date"];

    NSInteger*affectedDate=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"];


    NSString*appId =[eventDict objectForKey:@"appId"];
    NSString*eventId=[eventDict objectForKey:@"eventId"];
    NSString*location=[eventDict objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSString*municipality=[eventDict objectForKey:@"municipality"];
    NSString*title=[eventDict objectForKey:@"title"];




    Book1 *aBook=[[Book1 alloc] initWithDate:date affectedDate:affectedDate location:location municipality:municipality title:title];


    [appDelegate.books1 addObject:aBook];

    int count=[appDelegate.books1 count];



    }
```

the json format is given below

http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate your data in some different way.
Here is how I'd do that:

```
...
// why do you parse your json string two times?
//NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

// You have memory leak here. I assume that books1 and dates are both properties with "retain" flag set.
//appDelegate.books1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//appDelegate.dates =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array]
self.data = data;

// check that what we've parsed is NSArray
if (results && [results isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (NSDictionary *sectionDict in results) {
        if ([sectionDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSString *sectionTitle = [[sectionDict objectForKey:@"date"] description];
            NSArray *events = [sectionDict objectForKey:@"events"];
            if (date && events && [events isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[events count]];

                for (NSDictionary *eventDict in events) {
                    if ([eventDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                        [rows addObject:@"testRow"];
                    }
                }

                [data addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: sectionTitle, @"section", rows, @"rows", nil]];
            }

        }
    }
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tblView {
    return [data count];
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tblView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[data objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"rows"] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[data objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"section"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"DefaultCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if ( cell == nil ) {    
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rows"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks  for help how may i create object over here where you have written // create your object here   may i creat like this

Comment: can you please help me out i am creating object but its not working

Comment: so how can i show values location date affected date and title which are in dictionary

Comment: its working now but it shows testRow in cell value but i want the JSOn value of location in this and title in detailtextlabel of cell

Comment: i have also tried to make a data controller and then get dic item but it gives nil